# How to choose which view to choose at launch time in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, uiview, subview

I am writing an application that checks a boolean on a remote server. On the basis of received response - YES or NO - decides which UIView to launch at initialise time. Is the anyway to decide which UIView to pick?

Answer (score 0):

In or after your appDelegate's `applicationDidLaunch` method, you can set your main window's `rootViewController` to the ViewController you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

of course there is. one method is: you can make 2 xibs for different views then:

```
UIView *view_ = nil;

if(serverResponse)
{
NSArray *views= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewTypeOne1"
                                                  owner:self
                                                options:nil];

view_ = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 1];

}
else
{
NSArray *views= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewTypeOne2"
                                                  owner:self
                                                options:nil];

view_ = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 1];
}

//if it is to be set for a controller
controller.view = view_;
```